# search result click event is not working in gmail

Tags: jquery

I want to find the search email click event withing gmail.I have a chrome extension which is used withing gmail , and i want to do some stuff when mail open from the search result.

[image]

I want to find the click event of the search results.

I have tried below code for click event , but it's not working.

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="gs_ars"],[class^="gsar_"],[class^="gssb_"],[class^="gsar_a"] table tbody tr,tr[role="option"]', function() {console.log('xxxxyyyyzzz');});
```

Here is the html code for this.

```
<tbody role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="gs_ars50_8">
    <tr role="option" class="">
        <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="gsaq_a" id="gs_atqs50_0" aria-label="Search for &quot;arcade&quot;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 558px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 43px;">
                                <div class="asor asor_i4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 43px;">&nbsp;</div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 515px;">
                                <div class="gstq_d gstq_a gsfs" dir="ltr" style="width: 515px;"><b>arca</b>de</div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2">
                                <div class="gsaq_b" title="Remove from history" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 515px;">
                                <div class="gstq_e" style="width: 515px;"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="option" class="">
        <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="gsaq_a" id="gs_atqs50_1" aria-label="Search for &quot;arcade crm&quot;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 558px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 43px;">
                                <div class="asor asor_i4" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 43px;">&nbsp;</div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 515px;">
                                <div class="gstq_d gstq_a gsfs" dir="ltr" style="width: 515px;"><b>arca</b>de crm</div>
                            </td>
                            <td rowspan="2">
                                <div class="gsaq_b" title="Remove from history" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 515px;">
                                <div class="gstq_e" style="width: 515px;"></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="separator">
        <td>
            <div class="gssb_l"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="option" class="">
        <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_2" aria-label="Open mail &quot;Welcome to Arcade CRMFeb 7me, Maurice Koks&quot;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="asor_t0" style="width: 43px;">
                                <div class="asor_0">
                                    <div aria-hidden="true" class="gsoi gsoi_0 asor_v">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 529px;">
                                <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="asor_b asor_f" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">Welcome to <b>Arca</b>de CRM</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="25px" align="right">
                                                    <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Feb 7, 2018, 6:40 PM" aria-label="Feb 7, 2018, 6:40 PM" dir="ltr">Feb 7</div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="1" width="100%">
                                                    <div class="asor_e asor_f asor_k" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">me, Maurice Koks</div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="option" class="">
        <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_3" aria-label="Open mail &quot;Welcome to Arcade CRMFeb 8me, Maurice Koks&quot;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="asor_t0" style="width: 43px;">
                                <div class="asor_0">
                                    <div class="gsoi gsoi_0 asor_v">&nbsp;</div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 529px;">
                                <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="asor_b asor_f" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">Welcome to <b>Arca</b>de CRM</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="25px" align="right">
                                                    <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Feb 8, 2018, 6:55 PM" aria-label="Feb 8, 2018, 6:55 PM" dir="ltr">Feb 8</div>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="1" width="100%">
                                                        <div class="asor_e asor_f asor_k" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">me, Maurice Koks</div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="option" class="">
            <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
                <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_4" aria-label="Open mail &quot;TeaTime has invited You to Join Arcade CRMFeb 4Chirag, zxc
@arcadecrm.com&quot;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="asor_t0" style="width: 43px;">
                                    <div class="asor_0">
                                        <div class="gsoi gsoi_0 asor_v">&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 529px;">
                                    <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                            <tbody>


                         <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="asor_b asor_f" title="TeaTime has invited You to Join Arcade CRM" aria-label="TeaTime has invited You to Join Arcade CRM" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">TeaTime has invited You to Join <b>Arca</b>de CRM</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="25px" align="right">
                                                <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Feb 4, 2018, 2:12 AM" aria-label="Feb 4, 2018, 2:12 AM" dir="ltr">Feb 4</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="1" width="100%">
                                                <div class="asor_e asor_f asor_k" title="Chirag, asx@arcadecrm.com" aria-label="Chirag, asd@arcadecrm.com" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">Chirag, asd@<b>arca</b>decrm.com</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="option" class="">
    <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_5" aria-label="Open mail &quot;Arcade has invited You to Join Arcade CRMFeb 2John, asd@arcadecrm.com&quot;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="asor_t0" style="width: 43px;">
                            <div class="asor_0">
                                <div class="gsoi gsoi_0 asor_v">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 529px;">
                            <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="asor_b asor_f" title="Arcade has invited You to Join Arcade CRM" aria-label="Arcade has invited You to Join Arcade CRM" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr"><b>Arca</b>de has invited You to Join Arcade CRM</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="25px" align="right">


                                         <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Feb 2, 2018, 2:54 AM" aria-label="Feb 2, 2018, 2:54 AM" dir="ltr">Feb 2</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="1" width="100%">
                                                <div class="asor_e asor_f asor_k" title="John, asd@arcadecrm.com" aria-label="John, asd@arcadecrm.com" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">John, asd@<b>arca</b>decrm.com</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="option" class="">
    <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_6" aria-label="Open mail &quot;cre8ive has invited You to Join Arcade CRM12/11/17chirag, asd@arcadecrm.com&quot;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="asor_t0" style="width: 43px;">
                            <div class="asor_0">
                                <div class="gsoi gsoi_0 asor_v">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 529px;">
                            <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="asor_b asor_f" title="cre8ive has invited You to Join Arcade CRM" aria-label="cre8ive has invited You to Join Arcade CRM" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">cre8ive has invited You to Join <b>Arca</b>de CRM</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="25px" align="right">
                                                <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Dec 11, 2017, 12:17 PM" aria-label="Dec 11, 2017, 12:17 PM" dir="ltr">12/11/17</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="1" width="100%">
                                                <div class="asor_e asor_f asor_k" title="chirag, asd@arcadecrm.com" aria-label="chirag, asd@arcadecrm.com" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">chirag, asd@<b>arca</b>decrm.com</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="option" class="">
    <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_7" aria-label="Open mail &quot;google codeFeb 5Maurice Koks, me&quot;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="asor_t0" style="width: 43px;">
                            <div class="asor_0">
                                <div class="gsoi gsoi_0 asor_v">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 529px;">
                            <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="asor_b asor_f" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">google code</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="25px" align="right">
                                                <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Feb 5, 2018, 7:38 PM" aria-label="Feb 5, 2018, 7:38 PM" dir="ltr">Feb 5</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="1" width="100%">
                                                <div class="asor_e asor_f asor_k" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr">Maurice Koks, me</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="separator">
    <td>
        <div class="gssb_l"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="option" class="">
    <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="gsar_a" id="gs_ars50_8" aria-label="Open spreadsheet &quot;Arcade MessagesFeb 3Chirag Kanhasoft&quot;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 572px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="asor_t3" style="width: 43px;">
                            <div class="">
                                <div aria-hidden="true" class="gsoi gsoi_c asor_v"><img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_spreadsheet_x16.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 529px;">
                            <div class="gsar_b" style="width: 529px;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="asor_a">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="asor_b asor_f" style="width: 464px;" dir="ltr"><b>Arca</b>de Messages</div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="25px" align="right">
                                                <div class="asor_c asor_j" title="Feb 3, 2018, 5:29 AM" aria-label="Feb 3, 2018, 5:29 AM" dir="ltr">Feb 3</div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" width="100%">
                                                <div class="asor_d asor_f asor_k" style="width: 529px;"><span class="asor_e" dir="ltr"><span>Chirag Kanhasoft</span></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="separator">
    <td>
        <div class="gssb_l"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr role="option" class="">
    <td class="gssb_a gsfs" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">
        <div class="gsas_c asor_v" id="gs_asls50_9" aria-label="Search the web for &quot;arca&quot;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 568px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 37px;">
                            <div class="gsoi gsoi_w" style="width: 37px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="max-width: 531px;">
                            <div class="gsas_d" dir="ltr" style="max-width: 531px;">Search the web for "arca"</div>
                            <div class="gsas_e"><span class="gsas_a">Shift + Enter</span></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Which elements do you want to click on? I suspect the selector in `.on()` is not doing what you think.

Comment: `x,y,z table body tr` doesn't mean `x table body tr, y table body tr, z table body tr` -- they don't distribute. You need to write the latter format.

Comment: all those are totally different selectors,  you can check the html code

Comment: i want to fetch click event and want to do my stuff when email from search result is clicked. I tried all the selectors ,but none of the selectors is helpful to me.

Comment: All those selectors have tables inside them, so it looked like you wanted to be able to click on a row inside any of them.

Comment: You can check my jquery click event ,i tried most of the things,  but any selector is working